# R how to find duplicates inside one row

Tags: r, database, duplicates, survey

I have a very large dataset in R with 1797 observations (rows) and 24 variables (columns) corresponding to a survey conducted through EPFL community.

The respondents were asked at which frequency they perform 23 pro-environmental behaviours and they answered on a relative scale, leading to a score between 1 (for never) and 5 (for very often).

[image]

I would like to check for duplicated values inside each row in order to see if people answered randomly of seriously (e.g., someone having a lot of "3" values).

Therefore, I want to retrieve these duplicates per row, do you have an idea of how I can do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome at SO, please do always post a minimal reproducible example (R code + data) + the expected output for the example data. This make it easier for us to find an answer. Nobody likes to type data from a screen shot. THX :-)

Comment: First guess: The data should be transformed from columns into rows first using the `reshape2` package and the `melt` function inside the package...

Comment: Thanks ok. 
Well, I converted the rows to colums leading now and I want to perform the duplicated function per column individually (because now, each column corresponds to one of the 1797 respondents and each row to one of the 24 variables). 
Do you have an idea of how performing the duplicated function per column individually?

Comment: `lapply` works column-wise in a `data.frame`. What is your exact definition of a duplicate in your data set? You have five response values in 23 columns and 1797 rows, so you will always have duplicates (more than one value in a row or a column)?

Comment: I meant having a lot of same answers (for example, if one respondent has 15 answers with the same score like 4 over the 23 questions, it may be a redundant respondent). 
Thanks, I hope it was clearer

Comment: But now it's ok, I received helpful answers that permit me to perform what I wanted. 
Thanks a lot to all of you <3

Comment: Final "meta hint" about SO "rules": Please upvote all helpful answers (if you really found them helpful!) and mark the best answer by clicking the (green) "tick" to accept this as best answer. This makes it easier for other users to find good solutions in a short time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tidyverse` approach.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), 
                 q1 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q2 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q3 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q4 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q5 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q6 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q7 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q8 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q9 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q10 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE))


require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(question, value, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  #Give you the count for each answer
  count(value) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  #In addition, you can calculate the prop. of the same answer out of the 10 questions. 
  mutate(prop = n / 10)
```

Output:

```
   id value n prop
1   1     1 3  0.3
2   1     2 1  0.1
3   1     3 1  0.1
4   1     4 1  0.1
5   1     5 4  0.4
6   2     2 2  0.2
7   2     3 4  0.4
8   2     4 3  0.3
9   2     5 1  0.1
10  3     1 1  0.1
11  3     2 1  0.1
12  3     3 4  0.4
13  3     4 3  0.3
14  3     5 1  0.1
15  4     2 5  0.5
16  4     3 2  0.2
17  4     4 1  0.1
18  4     5 2  0.2
19  5     1 4  0.4
20  5     2 1  0.1
21  5     3 1  0.1
22  5     4 1  0.1
23  5     5 3  0.3
```

Comment: Ooooh nice great !! 
In which library / package can I find tidyverse please?

Comment: Glad I could help :). Tidyverse is an amazing number of packages with the same philosophy and ideas on how to analyze, visualize and model data. You can download it from cran (install.packages("tidyverse") in the console), and you can find more info here: https://www.tidyverse.org.

Answer (score 1):

To find duplicated elements in row:

```
duplicated(x)
```

> Example vector: `x <- c(1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6)`
>
> Result: `[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

To extract duplicated elements:

```
x[duplicated(x)]
```

> Example vector: `x <- c(1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6)`
>
> Result: `[1] 1 4`

Useful sources:

[R duplicated function manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html)

[Duplicated function examples](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/identifying-and-removing-duplicate-data-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the just want to count how often the questions were answered with the same value (no matter which question). This does it:

```
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2), Q1 = c(1, 4), Q2 = c(5, 2), Q3 = c(3, 2), Q4 = c(5, 2))
data

#   ID Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
# 1  1  1  5  3  5
# 2  2  4  2  2  2

melted.data <- melt(data, "ID") # , measure.vars = "")
melted.data
melted.data$count <- 1
melted.data   # "variable" contains the original column name now, "value" the cell content

#   ID variable value count
# 1  1       Q1     1     1
# 2  2       Q1     4     1
# 3  1       Q2     5     1
# 4  2       Q2     2     1
# 5  1       Q3     3     1
# 6  2       Q3     2     1
# 7  1       Q4     5     1
# 8  2       Q4     2     1

# group by "ID" + "value" columns and calculate the sum for the column "count"
# (I hate the "aggregate" syntax ;-)
aggregate( count ~ ID + value, data = melted.data, sum)

    ID value count
# 1  1     1     1
# 2  2     2     3
# 3  1     3     1
# 4  2     4     1
# 5  1     5     2
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much !!
I don't understand what is the " value " that appears in the last output, can you please explain me this as for the option "measure.vars" in the melt function?

Comment: Here is the output I have after having done this code: 
        ID     value     count
#1     4         1          1
#2     5         1          4
#3     7         1          9
#4     8         1          5
#5     10       1          1
#6     12       1          4

I always have "1" as a value, what does it mean?
Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry I finally understood by looking through all the data.
That's amazing and this is exactly what I wanted thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems OP is looking for `maximum number of duplicate answer` per row. An option can to use `apply` and `table` functions of `base-R` as:

**Option#1:**

```
# row-wise apply over columns starting with 'q'
df$MaxDup <- apply(df[,startsWith(names(df),"q")], 1,
                        function(x)sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)[1])

df
#   id q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 MaxDup
# 1  1  2  1  5  5  5  4  5  3  1   1      4
# 2  2  4  3  3  2  4  3  5  4  3   2      4
# 3  3  3  5  4  1  4  3  4  2  3   3      4
# 4  4  5  3  3  2  5  2  4  2  2   2      5
# 5  5  5  3  1  5  4  1  1  2  1   5      4
```

**Option#2:** All the row-wise duplicates listed in a column separated by `;`

```
df$DupCount <- apply(df[,startsWith(names(df),"q")], 1, function(x){
  dup <- sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)
  dup = dup[dup>1]
  paste0(paste(names(dup), dup, sep = "="), collapse = ";")
  })

df
#   id q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10    DupCount
# 1  1  2  1  5  5  5  4  5  3  1   1     5=4;1=3  <- 5=4 times; 1=3 times
# 2  2  4  3  3  2  4  3  5  4  3   2 3=4;4=3;2=2  <- 3=4 times; 4=3 times, 2=2 times
# 3  3  3  5  4  1  4  3  4  2  3   3     3=4;4=3  
# 4  4  5  3  3  2  5  2  4  2  2   2 2=5;3=2;5=2
# 5  5  5  3  1  5  4  1  1  2  1   5     1=4;5=3
```

**Data:** Taken from @DJV anser

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), 
                 q1 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q2 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q3 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q4 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q5 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q6 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q7 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q8 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q9 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE), 
                 q10 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DJV's sample data, we can find the mode for each row, then compute the ratio of use of this value :

```
modes <- as.numeric(apply(df[-1],1,function(x) names(sort(-table(x)))[1]))
ratios <- rowSums(df[-1]==modes)/(ncol(df)-1) # or df$ratios <-... to store it in a new col
# [1] 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.4
```